# How can I split strings up in c# to show different information and also convert a hexidecimal to a decimal at the same time?

Tags: c#

I have log files that just contain lines of information.  I made a program in which you drop the log file in and it converts it to something useful, but I'm having trouble separating lines and I feel like there's an excessive amount of line replaces I'm doing which only put in "2022", which I will have to change every year.

Let me explain the lines below:

```
{"uptime":62,"gps":"unknown","unique reads":0,"temperature":"25C","battery":"13500mV","charging":fal
{"uptime":122,"gps":"unknown","unique reads":0,"temperature":"25C","battery":"13500mV","charging":fa
{"uptime":182,"gps":"unknown","unique reads":1,"temperature":"25C","battery":"13500mV","charging":fa
aaA200000098985500012209101605112664FS                                                              
aaA200000098985500032209101605113566BS                                                              
aaA200000098973600012209101605173e98FS                                                              
aaA200000098973600012209101605173e98BS                                                              
aaA100000098985500102209101605132b91LS                                                              
aaA100000098973600072209101605200b91LS
```

I first start by getting rid of the worthless uptime lines; I don't need them. After that I need to edit the line information.  The first 4 items are the mat # (it's race timing software for runners). So, `aaA1` is `Mat 1`, etc, all the way up to 8.

Then after that is a hex with a bunch of leading zeros.  So, `000000989855` I would like to show as `10000469` or even show as "`Bib 469`".

The next 4 digits are used and can be eliminated.

After that is the date, so `220910` is `9/10/22`, followed by the time.  So, `1605112664` is `16:05:11.2664`.

Lastly, it's the reads.  So, `FS` is "`First Seen Read`", `BS` is "`Best Seen Read`" and `LS` is "`Last Seen Read`".

I can get the time to edit by itself, but not in the program with the rest of the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's how I edit the time in a standalone script:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String s = "2022/09101605112664";
        s = s.Insert(7, "/");
        s = s.Insert(10, " Time: ");
        s = s.Insert(19, ":");
        s = s.Insert(22, ":");
        s = s.Insert(25, ":");

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Here's the rest of my script:

```
using System.Media;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FalconBibConvert
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = dialog.FileName;
                }
            }
        }
        private void textBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

        private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
            if (files != null && files.Any())
                textBox1.Text = files.First();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please wait for completion pop-up. Bigger files = longer to process.\n A conversion may take several minutes.");
            string text = "";
            string converted = textBox1.Text + "Converted.log";
            string converted2 = textBox1.Text + "Converted2.log";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text))
            {
                string fileIN = textBox1.Text;
                string fileOUT = textBox1.Text + "Removed.log";
                if (File.Exists(fileIN))
                {
                    string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(fileIN);
                    foreach (string line in data)
                        if (!line.Contains("uptime"))
                            File.AppendAllText(fileOUT, line);
                }
            }
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text + "Removed.log"))
            {
                int i = 0;
                do
                {
                    i++;
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line != "")
                    {
                        line = line.Replace("aaA1", "\rMat 1\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA2", "\rMat 2\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA3", "\rMat 3\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA4", "\rMat 4\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA5", "\rMat 5\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA6", "\rMat 6\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA7", "\rMat 7\n");
                        line = line.Replace("aaA8", "\rMat 8\n");
                        line = line.Replace("FS", "\nFirst Seen Read\n**************\n");
                        line = line.Replace("BS", "\nBest Seen Read\n**************\n");
                        line = line.Replace("LS", "\nLast Seen Read\n**************\n");
                        line = line.Replace("000022", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000122", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000222", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000322", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000422", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000522", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000622", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000722", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000822", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("000922", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("001022", "\n2022/");
                        line = line.Replace("001122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("001922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("002922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("003922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("004922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("005922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("006922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("007922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("008922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("009922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0010922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0011922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0012922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0013922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0014922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0015922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0016022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0016122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0016222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0016322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("0016422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00222", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00322", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00422", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00522", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00622", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00722", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00822", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("00922", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("01022", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("01122", "\n");
                        line = line.Replace("000000", "");
                    }
                    using (StreamReader sr3 = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        var str = line;
                        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"(?s).{0,12}",
                        m => m.Value.EndsWith("\n") ? m.Value + "\t" : m.Value + "\n\t"));
                    }
                    string filepath = textBox1.Text;
                    void ReplaceInFile(
                      string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
                    {

                        var content = string.Empty;
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                        {
                            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            reader.Close();
                        }

                        content = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                        {
                            writer.Write(content);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                } while (sr.EndOfStream == false);

            }
            bool RemoveFirstLinesFromFile(string filePath, int skip)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                    return false;
                try
                {
                    var filePathOld = Path.Combine(filePath, ".old");
                    File.Move(filePath, filePathOld);
                    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, File.ReadAllLines(filePathOld).Skip(skip));
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            File.WriteAllText(converted, text);

            using (StreamReader sr5 = new StreamReader(converted))
            {
                string year = "2022";
                string line = sr5.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains(year) == true)
                {
                    //                   string path = converted;
                    //                   string s = line;
                    line = line.Insert(7, "/");
                    line = line.Insert(10, " Time: ");
                    line = line.Insert(19, ":");
                    line = line.Insert(22, ":");
                    line = line.Insert(25, ":");
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            File.WriteAllText(converted, text);
            {
 /*               using (StreamReader sr5 = new StreamReader(converted))
                {
                    string line = sr5.ReadLine();
                    if (line.Contains("2022") == true)
                    {
                        string path = converted;
                        string s = line;
                        s = s.Insert(7, "/");
                        s = s.Insert(10, " Time: ");
                        s = s.Insert(19, ":");
                        s = s.Insert(22, ":");
                        s = s.Insert(25, ":");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
 */
                    
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("CONVERSION COMPLETE!  See " + converted);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I did understood they are always on the same place, start at character x till y
With this information, you could just get from here to here from this string to build what you need
check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

We can **DEFINITELY** get rid of all those `line.Replace()` calls.

Start by making a class to represent the data in your lines:

```
public class RaceData
{
    public int Mat {get; set;}
    public int Bib {get;set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
    public string ReadType {get;set;}
}
```

Next we add a static method to the class to parse one line into on instance of the class. These lines are **Fixed-Width**, so we'll use a lot of `string.Substring()`:

```
public class RaceData
{
    public int Mat {get; set;}
    public int Bib {get;set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
    public string ReadType {get;set;}

    public static RaceData FromLine(string line)
    {
        return new RaceData() {
            Mat = line[3] - '0',
            Bib = int.Parse(line.Substring(4, 12), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) - 10000000,     
            Timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(line.Substring(20, 12), "yyMMddHHmmss", null).AddMilliseconds(int.Parse(line.Substring(32,4), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)),
            ReadType = line.Substring(36,2)
        };
    }
}
```

Now we can use this to add a short method to your form that can read the whole file. Don't forget to skip the JSON lines. You may also need to watch for a blank line at the end of the file. Note: the code below only needs to have one line in memory at a time, which is GREATLY more efficient:

```
public IEnumerable<RaceData> ReadFile(string path)
{
    return File.ReadLines(path).
         Where(line => !line.Startswith("{")).
         Select(RaceData.FromLine);
}
```

Finally, call the method in `button2_Click`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please wait for completion pop-up. Bigger files = longer to process.\n A conversion may take several minutes.");

    var resultPath = textBox1.Text + ".converted";
    using var sw = new StreamWriter(resultPath);
    foreach(var item in ReadFile(textBox1.Text))
    {
        sw.WriteLine($"Mat {item.Mat};Bib {item.Bib};{item.Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff};{item.ReadType}");
    }

    MessageBox.Show($"CONVERSION COMPLETE!\n\nSee {resultPath}");
}
```

You can kinda see it work here (Fiddle doesn't support File I/O, so that part is skipped):

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZsOq6O

I doubt this takes "several minutes" to run. I expect to it handle several thousands of records within a few seconds.